# ArcGIS project WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_32N to GCS_WGS_1984

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.2, error-999999

I'm new to GIS.

I have a shapefile for which I defined the coordinate system (using the Define Projection tool) to WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_32N and now
I'm trying to reproject the shapefile from WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_32N to GCS_WGS_1984.

I'm using the Project tool but I always get the following error and the projection never happens.

ERROR 999999: Error executing function
invalid extent for output coordinate system.
The operation was attempted on an empty geometry

I run the Repair Geometry tool ,it works fine, but then when I try to reproject to GCS_WGS_1984 I still get the same error as above

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I know similar questions have been asked in the past but I couldn't find one where someone gets an error.

Comment: You're using the 'project' tool?  Which one?  There's a bunch and only one will work for what you are trying to do ('Reproject').  Tools like 'Define Projection' will fail.

Comment: What's the error number at least? You can find that information if you open the Geoprocessing, Results window. If you're getting invalid geographic/datum transformation, try redefining the input data's coordinate system with the Define Projection tool or the data's property page in ArcCatalog.

Comment: Can you unproject the data in ArcMap?

Comment: mkennedy: the error I get is: 999999 error executing function
invalid extent for output coordinate system
the operation was attempted on an empty geometry

Comment: Run the [Repair Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00170000003v000000) tool on your original shapefile.  It sounds like you have NULL geometries that cannot be projected which is throwing the error.  Afterwards, try and reproject to the other coordinate system.

Comment: ew_gis: I still get the same error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide any requested clarifications. Revising your question should make what you are asking clearer. Until we know precisely what you have done and where you are stuck it is hard to answer.

Comment: Pls add to your question the boundaries of your original shape file... or check them your self. That way you can control if you have set the right coordinate system in the first place... I recommend to have a look this [coordinates calculator](http://www.deine-berge.de/Rechner/Koordinaten/).

Comment: As @wittich suggested, double-check that the input data is really in UTM 32North. An error of invalid extent/empty geometry implies that the features cannot be unprojected. That could be due to the coordinate system definition being incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much wittich & mkennedy, the guy who gave me the shapefile told me that it was in UTM_Zone_32N and I took it for granted. It turns out it uses a country specific coordinate system, I changed it and it works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [commented by @wittich](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171042/arcgis-project-wgs-1984-utm-zone-32n-to-gcs-wgs-1984#comment255302_171042):

> ... check [the boundaries of your original shape file] your self. That
>   way you can control if you have set the right coordinate system in the
>   first place... I recommend to have a look [at] this [coordinates
>   calculator](http://www.deine-berge.de/Rechner/Koordinaten/).

and [@mkennedy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171042/arcgis-project-wgs-1984-utm-zone-32n-to-gcs-wgs-1984#comment255338_171042):

> double-check that the input data is really in UTM 32North. An error of
>   invalid extent/empty geometry implies that the features cannot be
>   unprojected. That could be due to the coordinate system definition
>   being incorrect.